# Constructing an entire function with a given isolated zero set

Tags: complex-analysis

We know that a nonzero entire function on $\mathbb C$ has an isolated set of zeroes. Is it the case that, given an isolated set, there is an entire function which vanishes precisely on that set? If the set is finite, we can obviously use a polynomial, but what if the set is infinite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, check out the Weierstrass Factorization Theorem.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_factorization_theorem